# If I type a single word in 's', it says index out of range. If the last word in 's' starts with a consonant, it will still say index out of range

Tags: python, indexing, range

```
def to_pig_latin(s):
    j = 0 # points to first character in word
    i = 0
    new_sentence_1 = '' # variable to store strings being changed
    vowel_position = 0 # show the position of the first vowel
    number_of_words = 0
    number_of_spaces = s.count(" ") 
    number_of_words = number_of_spaces + 1

    space_position = s.find(" ") # find the position of the first space
    sent = s[:space_position] # slice the first word of the sentence
    old_sent = s[len(sent)+1:] # stores the old sentence without the first word of s

    while number_of_spaces >= 0:
        if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: # checks if first character is a vowel
            new_sentence = sent + "way" # adds 'way' to the first word
            new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence # adds the words

        else: # if first character is not equal to a vowel
            for i in range(len(sent)):
                # check to see if first character in s is a vowel
                if s[i] == 'a': 
                    break
                if s[i] == 'e':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'i':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'o':
                    break
                if s[i] == 'u':
                    break

            vowel_position = i # takes position of first vowel reached in word
            consonant_sequence = sent[:vowel_position] # stores all the consonants up to the first vowel, but not the first vowel
            sent = sent[vowel_position:] # slices the word from the first vowel to the end
            new_sentence = sent + 'a' + consonant_sequence + 'ay' # adds strings
            new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence # adds the words

        s = old_sent # takes the value of old_sent
        space_position = s.find(" ") # find the position of the first space
```

> How do i change the part below in order to for it to check even if there is one word in 's'? Or if the last word in the string 's' ends with a word that begins with one or more consonant?

```
        if space_position == -1:
            space_position = len(s)
            sent = s[:space_position]
            if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
                new_sentence = sent + "way"
                new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence
                break
            else:
                for i in range(len(sent)):
                    if s[i] == 'a':
                        break
                    if s[i] == 'e':
                        break
                    if s[i] == 'i':
                        break
                    if s[i] == 'o':
                        break
                    if s[i] == 'u':
                        break

            vowel_position = i
            consonant_sequence = sent[:vowel_position]
            sent = sent[vowel_position:]
            new_sentence = sent + 'a' + consonant_sequence + 'ay'
            new_sentence_1 = new_sentence_1 + ' ' + new_sentence            


        sent = s[:space_position]
        old_sent = s[len(sent)+1:]
        number_of_spaces = s.count(" ")
        number_of_words = number_of_spaces + 1

    return new_sentence_1[1:]
```

---

```
# test program for english/piglatin translator

import piglatin

choice = input ("(E)nglish or (P)ig Latin?\n")
action = choice[:1]
if action == 'E':
    s = input("Enter an English sentence:\n")
    new_s = piglatin.to_pig_latin(s)
    print("Pig-Latin:")
    print(new_s)
elif action =='P':
    s = input("Enter a Pig Latin sentence:\n")
    new_s = piglatin.to_english(s)
    print("English:")
    print(new_s)
```

---

> (E)nglish or (P)ig Latin? E Enter an English sentence: apple     Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py",
>   line 9, in    File "/Users/azhar/Desktop/Computer
>   Science/Assignments/Assignment 4 (Functions & Strings)/piglatin.py",
>   line 44, in to_pig_latin
>       if sent[j] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]: builtins.IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You have a for-loop over all numbers till length of `sent` but try to index into `s`:

```
for i in range(len(sent)):
    if s[i] == 'a':
        break
```

Except of raising an IndexError if len(s) < len(sent) this for-loop does nothing useful.

Comment: just loop over sent using enumerate if necessary

Comment: What the loop actually does, it searches for the first vowel in 'sent'. Once it reaches the first vowel. It just takes the position and saves it in vowel_position. But if, for e.g, I only have one word, say 'apple' in s. It will say 'string index out of range'.

Comment: How to loop over sent, using enumerate?